# aspnet multiview jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, multiview

I came with a very weird situation.

I have  form with a AspNet multiview control on it.
I want to save its content every N seconds. So I send an ajax Post request every N seconds.

The issue comes after the postback number 10. The view state seems to get corrupted after the Post number 8 and all the controls inside the non visible view loose their values.

My aspx page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="multiview-ajax-bug-    test.aspx.cs"
Inherits="multiview_ajax_bug_test"  Theme=""%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script src="JS/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src='<%= ResolveUrl("~/JS/auto-save.js") %>'></script>
</head>

<body>

<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <div id="subnavigation">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnk_one" runat="server" Text="Page1" Font-Bold="true" OnClick="lnk_one_Click"></asp:LinkButton></li>
            <li>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnk_two" runat="server" Text="Page2" OnClick="lnk_two_Click"></asp:LinkButton></li>
            <li>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnk_three" runat="server" Text="Page3" OnClick="lnk_three_Click"></asp:LinkButton></li>
            <li>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnk_four" runat="server" Text="Page4" OnClick="lnk_four_Click"></asp:LinkButton></li>
        </ul>
        <asp:MultiView ID="ProjectMultiView" runat="server" ActiveViewIndex="0">
            <asp:View ID="vw_one" runat="server">
                one
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="one"></asp:TextBox>
            </asp:View>
            <asp:View ID="vw_two" runat="server">
                two
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="two"></asp:TextBox>
            </asp:View>
            <asp:View ID="vw_three" runat="server">
                three
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="three"></asp:TextBox>
            </asp:View>
            <asp:View ID="vw_four" runat="server">
                four
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="four">
                </asp:TextBox>
            </asp:View>
        </asp:MultiView>
        <div class="clearboth">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

    // save every two minutes
    $(function () {
        var formId = '<%= Form.ClientID  %>';
        var url = location.href;

        var interval = 1 * 1 * 1000; // 1 secs
        setInterval(saveDraft, interval);

        function saveDraft() {
            autoSave(formId, url);
        }

    });
</script>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

My autosave function:

```
// auto-save.js
// Posts an ajax request to the server, the server side needs to check that it is an ajax request and save the content
// Requires JQuery 1.10 at least

function autoSave(formId, url, statusControlId) {
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    cache: false,
    method: "POST",
    data: $("#" + formId).serialize(),
    success: function (data) {
        if (statusControlId) {
            $("#" + statusControlId).html("");
            $("#" + statusControlId).html("success");
        }
    },
    error: function () {
        if (statusControlId) {
            $("#" + statusControlId).html("");
            $("#" + statusControlId).html("error");
        }
    }
});
}
```

Code behind:

```
using System;


public partial class multiview_ajax_bug_test : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void lnk_one_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ProjectMultiView.SetActiveView(vw_one);
    }

    protected void lnk_two_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ProjectMultiView.SetActiveView(vw_two);
    }

    protected void lnk_three_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       ProjectMultiView.SetActiveView(vw_three);
    }

    protected void lnk_four_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ProjectMultiView.SetActiveView(vw_four);
    }
}
```

Is there anything obvious that I'm missing, or is it a bug on the Multiview control?

Comment: so data is corrupted in ~10 seconds?

Comment: It is not corrupted after 10 seconds. It depends on the frequency the ajax post is executed. After 8 ajax post the viewstate is lost for any view of the aspnet multiview control that is not visible in the page. The strange of the situation is that I looked at the requests and responses using Fiddler and the requests are all the time the same (same variables and lenght). But the response length changes after post number 8. Maybe is some kind of security mechanism of ASPNET that I cannot understand?